# PHP - How to get "all two digits number" that their addition give a specific number

Tags: php, loops

I create a little mind game that need to guess for a number from 1 to 18 the two numbers combination that give this number for example:

```
1: 10 (1+0 = 1)
2: 11 (1+1 = 2)
3: 12 (1+2 = 3), 21 (2+1 = 3)
4: 22 (2+2 = 4), 31 (3+1= 4), 13 (1+3 = 4)
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

How to get for each number this numbers list ending with 18?

Comment: Hello Welcome, please read the following article that might help you get the answer you need: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I don't quite understand the example. How are the numbers on the right hand side being picked? Is the computer doing the guessing or is it the player? "the two numbers combination" - so what two numbers add together to make that number? I'm quite confused. Also, what is it that you need help with - I think I'm mis-understanding what "how to get for each umber this numbers list ending with 18" as well. Please **edit your question** to clarify these details, so that more people are able to help you.

Comment: Hello @Toastrackenigma, the computer give the player the number for example: 4 and say: enter all numbers of one or two digits that their digits addition give the number 4.

so the player should think and enter: 22 (2+2 =4), 13 (1+3 = 4), 31 (3+1 = 4)

Comment: Oh, I understand now - that's quite cool! So, essentially, what you want to do is use PHP to generate all of those numbers for the number `18` - e.g it should give back `99`?

Answer (score 1):

```
for($target = 1; $target < 19; $target++) {
    echo "$target: ";
    for($i = 10; $i<100; $i++) {
        $parts = str_split((string) $i);
        if (array_sum($parts) == $target) {
            echo "$i ";
        }
    }

    echo "\n";
}
```

`$target` is the sum we're currently looking for. The inner loop checks all 2-digit numbers for all sum targets, using standard PHP functions str_split() and array_sum() to split the numbers and calculate the sum of the parts.

Output:

```
1: 10 
2: 11 20 
3: 12 21 30 
4: 13 22 31 40 
5: 14 23 32 41 50 
6: 15 24 33 42 51 60 
7: 16 25 34 43 52 61 70 
8: 17 26 35 44 53 62 71 80 
9: 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 90 
10: 19 28 37 46 55 64 73 82 91 
11: 29 38 47 56 65 74 83 92 
12: 39 48 57 66 75 84 93 
13: 49 58 67 76 85 94 
14: 59 68 77 86 95 
15: 69 78 87 96 
16: 79 88 97 
17: 89 98 
18: 99
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply looking to create a game that allows a user to enter a number that becomes a sum of its digits and compare it to a computer generated number

```
<?php
function sum($carry, $num){
  $carry += $num;
  return $carry;
}
function game($computer, $guess){
  if($computer === array_reduce(str_split($guess), 'sum')){
    return 'win';
  }
  return 'lose';
}
// force computer to choose 9
$computer = 9; $guess = 18;
echo game($computer, $guess);
// random 1-18 computer choice - will show win when computer picks 4
$computer = rand(1, 18); $guess = 22;
echo game($computer, $guess);
?>
```

You could also do like:

```
<?php
class GuessingGame{
  public $computerFunc;
  public function __construct($computerFunc = null){
    $this->computerFunc = $computerFunc;
  }
  public function guess($guess){
    $user = array_reduce(str_split($guess), function($carry, $num){
      $carry += $num;
      return $carry;
    });
    if(call_user_func($this->computerFunc) === $user){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
function computerFunc(){
  return rand(1, 18);
}
$game = new GuessingGame('computerFunc');
$test = $game->guess(22) ? 'win' : 'lose';
function guarantee(){
  return 9;
}
$game->computerFunc = 'guarantee';
$test2 = $game->guess(18) ? 'win' : 'lose';
$test .= ' ----- '.$test2 ;
echo $test;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To create this kind of set you can use a nested for loop, with each loop iterating from zero to the maximum, which in this case 9 since you want all the resulting pairs of addends to be two digits.

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 9; $x++) {
    for ($y = 0; $y <= 9; $y++) {
        $result[$x + $y][] = $x . $y;
    }
}
```

Then output each set of addend pairs.

```
foreach ($result as $sum => $addends) {
    echo "$sum: " . implode(' ', $addends) . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using more than one loop is a waste of processing power because it will perform unnecessary/useless iterations.  For each game, you will determine a single random number for your player to "work on".  Use a single loop with simple subtraction to determine all of the correct answers.  Don't use brute force if you are going to generate this lookup array each time; **use one loop and mathematical logic**.  (Realistically, you can/should just hardcode the full look-up array without any noticeable memory loss; I'll assume this is an academic/personal coding challenge.)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kscvf))

```
$random_target = rand(1,18);
echo "Find all two digit numbers whose individual digits add up to: " , $random_target , "\n\n";

for ($x = 1; $x < 10; ++$x) {  // the tens digit
    if (($diff = $random_target - $x) >= 0 && $diff < 10 ) {  // if ones digit is only "1 digit" it qualifies
        $result[] = "$x$diff";
    }
}

var_export($result);
```

A possible output:

Find all two digit numbers whose individual digits add up to: 13

```
array (
  0 => '49',
  1 => '58',
  2 => '67',
  3 => '76',
  4 => '85',
  5 => '94',
)
```

p.s. If you want to build the full look-up array, use @Don'tPanic's lean technique (no wasted iterations).  Then hardcode that result into your script -- never needing to generate the correct results again.

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 9; ++$x) {
    for ($y = 0; $y <= 9; ++$y) {
        $result[$x + $y][] = "$x$y";
    }
}
var_export($result);
```